# Como realizar una consulta sin subquery que devuelva el mismo resultado de una con subquery en sql server

Tags: sql

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT AR.ARTICULO,AR.DESCRIPCION,AP.PRECIO,
              (SELECT AF.FOTO FROM EXSD.ARTICULO_FOTO AF WHERE AF.SECUENCIA = 1 AND AF.ARTICULO = AR.ARTICULO) AS 'FOTO' 
             FROM EXSD.ARTICULO AR JOIN EXSD.ARTICULO_PRECIO AP ON AR.ARTICULO = AP.ARTICULO 
            JOIN EXSD.VERSION_NIVEL VN ON AP.NIVEL_PRECIO = VN.NIVEL_PRECIO 
            AND AP.VERSION = VN.VERSION AND VN.MONEDA = AP.MONEDA 
             WHERE AP.NIVEL_PRECIO = 'ND-LOCAL' AND 
             AP.VERSION = '11' AND AP.MONEDA = 'L' AND VN.SINC_MOVIL = 'S'
```

La cual me devuelve el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y estoy intentando realizar esa misma consulta pero sin el subquery :

```
 SELECT AR.ARTICULO,AR.DESCRIPCION,AP.PRECIO,ARTICULO_FOTO.FOTO
             FROM EXSD.ARTICULO AR JOIN EXSD.ARTICULO_PRECIO AP ON AR.ARTICULO = AP.ARTICULO 
            JOIN EXSD.VERSION_NIVEL VN ON AP.NIVEL_PRECIO = VN.NIVEL_PRECIO 
            AND AP.VERSION = VN.VERSION AND VN.MONEDA = AP.MONEDA 
             join EXSD.ARTICULO_FOTO on 
             ARTICULO_FOTO.SECUENCIA = 1 
             AND ARTICULO_FOTO.ARTICULO = AR.ARTICULO 
             WHERE AP.NIVEL_PRECIO = 'ND-LOCAL' AND 
             AP.VERSION = '11' AND AP.MONEDA = 'L' AND VN.SINC_MOVIL = 'S'
```

sin embargo no estoy obteniendo el mismo resultado :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo obtener el mismo resutado de la primer consulta en la segunda sin tener que usar el subquery?????????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo resolví con un Left Join:

```
SELECT AR.ARTICULO,AR.DESCRIPCION,AP.PRECIO,AF.FOTO
             FROM EXSD.ARTICULO AR
             JOIN EXSD.ARTICULO_PRECIO AP ON AR.ARTICULO = AP.ARTICULO 
            JOIN EXSD.VERSION_NIVEL VN ON AP.NIVEL_PRECIO = VN.NIVEL_PRECIO 
            AND AP.VERSION = VN.VERSION AND VN.MONEDA = AP.MONEDA 
            LEFT JOIN EXSD.ARTICULO_FOTO AF
            ON AF.ARTICULO=AP.ARTICULO AND AF.SECUENCIA=1
             WHERE AP.NIVEL_PRECIO = 'ND-LOCAL' AND 
             AP.VERSION = '11' AND AP.MONEDA = 'L' AND VN.SINC_MOVIL = 'S'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* PRUEBA CON ESTO, El error en tu query es que FOTO NO ESTAS USAND EL ALIAS AF  */
SELECT 
     AR.ARTICULO
    ,AR.DESCRIPCION
    ,AP.PRECIO
    ,AF.FOTO 
 FROM EXSD.ARTICULO         AR 
 JOIN EXSD.ARTICULO_PRECIO  AP  ON AR.ARTICULO      = AP.ARTICULO 
 JOIN EXSD.VERSION_NIVEL    VN  ON AP.NIVEL_PRECIO  = VN.NIVEL_PRECIO AND AP.VERSION = 
VN.VERSION AND VN.MONEDA = AP.MONEDA 
 JOIN EXSD.ARTICULO_FOTO    AF  ON AF.ARTICULO      = AR.ARTICULO
WHERE AP.NIVEL_PRECIO   = 'ND-LOCAL' 
  AND AP.VERSION        = '11' 
  AND AP.MONEDA         = 'L' 
  AND VN.SINC_MOVIL     = 'S'
  AND AF.SECUENCIA      = 1
```

Comment: Espero te resuelva..

Comment: Lamentablemente no. Me devuelve 2 registros y si se observa en la imagen debería devolver 5 registros. L o que pasa es que algunos articulos tienen el campo foto en null. Como podría incluir esos campos null en la respuesta para que devuelva los mismos 5 registros del primer query?

Comment: Tienes toda la razón. es un left join lo que resuelve